# Broken wall box, how to fix?

Tags: electrical, walls, receptacle

It's old electric wall box for plug receptacle. Pulled a plug and it pulled box with it. It has two screw holes and one of them is broken.

Obviously in not gonna take it apart and install a new one.

Broken screw hole:

[image: Broken screw hole]

From side:

[image: From side]

Covered:

[image: Covered]

Answer (score 1):

If you can't repair the screw hole, the best option is to replace the box. If it's nailed into a stud and can't be easily removed, you might have to cut into it and destroy it. Once it is removed, you can replace it with an old work box mounted into the existing hole.

Comment: Can't I replace the metal hole with another one? I never replaced wall boxes before and sounds like a lot of work.

Comment: Possibly, but I'm not sure how. The boxes we have in the US don't typically have metal screw holes if the box itself is plastic. Maybe yours can be replaced?